# Cache response based on User Session

Tags: flask

I want to implement some caching with `Flask-Caching`. In particular I want to cache API response since the frequency of data update is very rare, less than once per day.
I can't figure how to implement cache based on user. The API response include some information that is calculated based on the user is requesting the info.

Which is the right way to implement cache per user and not generic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a different result to be cached for each user, then you need to include some unique user data as part of the cache key. Think of it like a dictionary object where you want to store a record for each user.

Flask-Caching allows you to specify a key prefix as a parameter to `cached`.

```
@cache.cached(timeout=50, key_prefix=user_id)
```

You are likely to want to get the user_id from the request data, in which case you can use the `make_cache_key` option which gives you access to the flask request context.

```
def make_key():
    ...

@cache.cached(timeout=50, make_cache_key=make_key)
```

See the [Flask-Caching documentation](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#make-custom-cache-key)